# Service Model performance counters Instance Name

Tags: c#, wcf, performancecounter

I am trying to connect directly to the performance counters emitted by ServiceModel (for services, endpoints and operations). The problem is that when I try to correlate with a certain service (or endpoint/operation) I need to specified instance name of the counter.

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/performance-counters/) the pattern by which instance name is simple,
however in certain cases when one of the components of the instance name (uri, contract name, etc.) is too long it’s shortened and hash code is added at either the beginning or the end of the string.The article doesn’t specify how it’s hashed.

So my question is there a way to get ServiceModel instance name based on the service name and it's address

Answer (score 2):

I know it is not ideal, but you could copy the current .NET implementation for generating counter instance names to your own code/application to programatically generate the same names from the full service name and address.

You can see the code used by WCF here:

For SerivcePerformanceCounters:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Diagnostics/ServicePerformanceCountersBase.cs,6d61d34585241697

For EndpointPerformanceCounters:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Diagnostics/EndpointPerformanceCountersBase.cs,e3319d41297320e3

For OperationPerformanceCounters:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Diagnostics/OperationPerformanceCountersBase.cs,5e170817afd5d0ba

The downside is that any change to the .NET algorithm for naming instances will break your implementation.

I'm as frustrated as you surely are, but haven't found a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I just want to know if you have try this solution and got consistent results

Comment: Sadly, I still cannot say with confidence that this is a robust approach. I was just researching this same topic a few days ago and came across your question so I wanted to share what I had found. I'm still trying to find a workaround (hardcoding the names generated by .net in a configuration file and update them manually when a counter changes, for example). Although copying the .net naming algorithm works as a proof of concept I don't know yet if it is worth the hassle.

Comment: Well I have a question regarding Operations Counter, actually we have to provide 3 parameter to the GetShortName .Net method, my question is about the third one which is the uri, can you give me an example of it or what they mean by that param