# WCF "Service" Performance Counters Naming

Tags: wcf, performancecounter

I'm only interested in Service Performance Counters at the moment and for the life of me, I cannot figure out what is the naming pattern for these.

According to [WCF Performance Counters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx), the pattern is

```
ServiceName@ServiceBaseAddress
```

yet I see all kinds of, pardon my French, crap:

- `AsiaService@http:||asiaservice.aeroclub.int:8004|`
- `PricingSchemeService@|Services|v2|PricingSchemeService.svc`
- `CompanyProfilesService@09.1|CompanyProfilesService.svc`
- `PersonalProfilesService@341|PersonalProfilesService.svc`
- `PersonalProfilesService@882|PersonalProfilesService.svc`

Now, the first one is more-or-less clear: stuff after `@` is indeed a base address (uglied-up, though -- I think perf counter names are not allowed to have slashes in them) of a self-hosted WCF service.

Second one is IIS-hosted and the "base address" is indeed relative URL to the service.

Third baffles me to no end. `09.1` does not look like anything: it is not a part of a relative URL, it is not a PID, nor it is a port number.

Two last ones are completely bonkers. There are indeed two instances of `PersonalProfilesService.svc` hosted under different URLs, yet perf counter names make no mention of said URLs and contain unidentifiable digits after `@`. These are again not PIDs, not port numbers, not URLs.

Help me maintain my sanity and pretty please, point to a document where all of this is described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh nevermind. Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35809016/60188). In my particular situation, the third service is hosted under a longish URL ending with `../v0.1/CompanyProfilesService.svc`, hence the `.1` part; the two extra digits are hash value of the original string. Ditto for the last two services.